# Seems like long boot time

Tags: windows-10, boot

Hi.

I've got a problem on my Windows 10 Edu which I wanted to fix some time ago. I bought Crucial BX500 and it was booting fast (about 8-10s) for the first week but then I recalled that I have to install chipset, acpi and usb drivers. I used DriverBooster for this.

That was end of my fast boot and boot time has been extended to 25-30 seconds.

What did i do to shorten it:

- disabled all startup programs (I always run needed program by myself)
- tried all "fast boot" options in bios
- disabled "waiting for network to logon" in gpedit
- cleaned registry and programs caches
- enlarged paging file (total 32GB)
- disabled ULPS for SSD in regedit (but I don't think it could even help)
- booted PC without any USB device connected (no effect)
- disabled Windows Defender and Firewall
- changed power plan to high performance

I also turned off "turn on fast startup" but it only hid the booting circle under Windows logo. Time was the same.

After recording WPA I noticed that winlogon init and pre session init are a bit too long. Especially pre session init where I don't see anything but the Idle.[1]
But I don't know much about analyzing .etl files so can you help me? Is 25 seconds a normal SSD boot time?

Attaching .etl: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z7ZYe3kUEUEYEGNLgpbeCxuHbFbgPG_n

Comment: Good choice, "ULPS can cause crashing/stuttering/reduced scaling when enabled. ULPS is always enabled by default." https://www.overclock.net/forum/70-amd-drivers-overclocking-software/1587347-how-disable-ulps-cfx-windows-10-crimson.html

Comment: Bad choice, "disabled Windows Defender and Firewall" ... "I also turned off "turn on fast startup"" why would you turn off FAST STARTUP, I thought you were looking for FASTER start times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

25 seconds is absolutely normal for a laptop or desktop with normal software processes loading (over 100 for my laptop and near 100 for my desktop). By the time Office, Adobe and other processes start, I am looking at about 1 minute for both machines. My iPhone takes between 45 seconds and a minute. This is for unfettered smooth running

Comment: even if the only change I made there is installing chipset, disk and usb drivers?

Comment: Even with fully updated drivers it still takes time to load the OS, Power Management, AntiVirus, Acrobat (many of us use this), Communication processes (NIC, WIreless), Cortana and Indexing and so on.